# Using BigQuery results with FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am doing R&D on analysis tools and which should I implement for my project to use. I have looked at firebase analytics and it seems to be a great tool to imply. I have learnt that we can create audiences and then target push notifications on them but what if I have exported my events data to BigQuery,ran some SQL queries on that data and then I want to send push notifications on the users who were output of that data? Is there any way to get push notification tokens from the output of BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to directly export just all tokens from an FCM project to BigQuery. But you can implement this yourself, by posting the token from the Android app to a Cloud Function, which then passes it to BigQuery.

You could save yourself some coding by [automatically sending the FCM message data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#bigquery_data_export). But this feels a bit like a chicken-and-egg problem, as you then first need to send a message to each client to get their token (`instance_id`) into that table.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for responsding quick. I already have FCM tokens corresponding to user_id in my backend as I am using firebase for push notifications. Based on the filter I can use those tokens and send push notifications, right? Also, if you have any idea and can throw some light on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/54683792/3484668?