# Google Tag Manager with Facebook Analytics for Apps

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, facebook-analytics

I have integrated my firebase analytics in apps and want to use facebook analytics to target ad campaigns. But, I don't want to code everything and integrate facebook analytics. I have heard that Google Tag Manager integreates with both facebook and firebase analytics. Can I share events from Firebase Analytics to Facebook Analytics via Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager does not integrate with Facebook. You can find a list of integrations here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106924?hl=en